# How to extend the ion-loading till page renders in ionic-5

Tags: ionic5

I've to make 3 back-end api-call before showing the UI screen. So, I used the ion-loading below snippet,

I'm presenting the loader in 1st backend call and it get closed in the first call itself. But I've to close the loader in third api call to show the screen.

How to extend the loader till the last api call,

```
this.presentLoading();

 async presentLoading() {
    this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      spinner: null,
      cssClass: 'custom-class custom-loading',
    });
    await this.loading.present();
  }
```

Comment: Add the calls inside the loader like await. this.loading.present().then(() => { // api calls here }); and in the third api call, inside subscribe((res) = > { this.loadingController.dismiss();...});

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this would be to call `.then()` on `loadingController.create()` and then process all your api calls inside there. Here's how I would organize it so that your loading controller is dismissed properly either when the 3 api calls succeed or when one of them fails. This setup assumes your api call functions return promises.

```js
this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Loading, please wait...'
    }).then((loading) => {

      loading.present();

      Promise.all([apiCallOne(), apiCallTwo(), apiCallThree()])
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          loading.dismiss();
        })
        .then((results) => {
          // do something with results ...
          loading.dismiss();
        });

    });
```